# Country expected, got String error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models "Country" and "League", Country has many Leagues and League belongs to Country. When adding a league, I have a listbox with countries and when the form is submitted, the actual country is send:

```
{"commit"=>"Create League",
 "authenticity_token"=>"wuAuj5vowkk2R56TuFkWE8J3x3vue5RbnNPcbpjuG3Q=",
 "utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "league"=>{"league_short"=>"CL",
 "country"=>"England",
 "level"=>"2",
 "league"=>"The Championship"}}
```

But then I get this error message:

```
Country expected, got String
```

In the Country model I have country_id (integer) and country (string) as fields, in the League model I have country as a string field. In the League controller I have this to pouplate the dropdown: `@countries = Country.dropdown_list`. In the league/new view I have this select field: `<%= f.select :country, @countries %>`. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send country_id (which is the primary key) instead of name 'England' in that request. The relationships are associated with the primary keys.

```
<%= f.select :country, Country.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] } %>
```

Comment: I just did this: `<%= f.select :artist, Artist.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id] } %>` and got this `Artist(#2198585660) expected, got String(#2151988680)`

Comment: @JoeSak , I had this same issue and had added `:artist` instead of `:artist_id` to the permitted parameters list in my controller.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use :country_id instead of :country

```
<%= f.select :country_id, Country.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]} %>
```

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error:

```
Artist (#xxx) expected, got String (#xxx)
```

This was how I fixed it in Rails 3.0.x:

```
class OtherModel
   belongs_to :artist

   validates :artist, :presence => true

   #...
end

<%= form_for_other.collection_select :artist_id, 
                                     Artist.all, :id, :name,
                                     :prompt => true %>
```

So it worked when I set the method on the collection_select input to the foreign key instead of the model name

Comment: Where did you put this, the artist model?

Comment: @hubble where did you place the validation?

Comment: In whatever model "belongs_to" or "has_one" Artist

Answer (score 1):

The League model should reference country by its id ( country_id ) and not the string.

Answer (score 0):

for others who met the same problem:

this error is caused when you have two fields in your form like:

```
video: 'some string'
video['url']:  'some url'
```

then rails will crash with the error: expected Hash (got String) for param

the solution is quite simple: change 'video' to something else. e.g.:

```
video_origin_url: 'some string'
video['url']: 'some url'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error:

Country (#xxx) expected, got String (#xxx)
This was how I fixed it in Rails 3.0.x:

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all.collect,  :id, :name %>
```