# Rails model error AssociationTypeMismatch expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, associations

I'm attempting to create a Rails 3 app with three models, with `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships. I'm getting an `AssociationTypeMismatch` error when I try to submit a form. Specifically `Location(#70232625418240) expected, got String(#70232609906560)` The models I've set up are:

- Food
- Location
- Month

Right now I'm working on connecting the Food and Location models. I've created a simple form form `@food` which pulls in the entries from `@location` as checkboxes. I'd like to select different locations by checking them off, and associate them with the `locations` index in my Food model.

I'm trying to have the checkboxes submit as an array, so I can associate the locations with the foods. So I'm submitting the location ids, which I believe will allow me to pull in the location Name for each one associated with a food entry.

My models are set up this way:

**food.rb**

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area, :description, :icon, :iconSource, :image, :locations, :months, :name, :source, :type, :month_id
  has_many :locations
  has_many :months
end
```

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :region, :regionName, :state, :title, :food_id, :month_id, :locations_id
  has_many :months
  belongs_to :foods
end
```

The form I have set up looks like this:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @food do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name", :class => 'field-name' %>
    </div>

    <% for location in Location.find(:all) %>
        <div>
          <%= check_box_tag "food[locations_id][]", location.id %>
          <%= location.title %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

The Foods controller is using the create action to process the form:

**foods_controller.rb**

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foods = Food.all
  end
  def new
    @food = Food.new
    @locations = Location.all
  end
  def create
    @food = Food.new(params[:food])
    if @food.save
        redirect_to foods_url(@food), :notice => "Food created!"
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

The form submits just fine when I'm only entering data relating to the Foods model. But when I select one the of Location checkboxes and try to submit the form, I'm getting this `Location(#70232625418240) expected, got String(#70232609906560)` error. Here's the rest of the output:

```
app/controllers/foods_controller.rb:10:in `new'
app/controllers/foods_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"QThXhDG8pPJcRVTTW6FXmo6MhGcoUeUspBhRtrbsbig=",
 "food"=>{"name"=>"Apple",
 "locations"=>["1"]},
 "commit"=>"Post"}
```

After looking into this for a few hours, I have tried everything I could find to fix this. I realize that I [need to be using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716412/country-expected-got-string-error) the `location_id` instead of `locations`. But after that, I'm turning up empty on other solutions here. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `location_ids` instead of `locations_id`:

```
<%= check_box_tag food[location_ids], location.id -%>
```

Please also read the answers to [rails 3 has_many :through Form with checkboxes](/q/5054633).

### Edit:

`:location_id` to `food[location_ids]`

and add this `location_id` in to the `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Ok, so when I use this, I no longer get an error on submit. But it looks like the form is submitting empty for Locations. Do I need to update my controller at all for this to work? I'm trying to display the locations on the index view by using `<%= food.locations %>`. Is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem I solves it by using accepts_nested_attributes_for.

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area, :description, :icon, :iconSource, :image, :locations, :months,  :name, :source, :type, :month_id
  has_many :locations
  has_many :months

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => :true

  end
```

You can refer to this video which will explain better than me what you need to do in view and else.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1