# rails form select multiple gives empty first value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have defined has_and_belongs_to_many associations between Meals and Recipes. In the Meals create form, I am using a select to populate the recipes.

```
<%= f.select :recipes, Recipe.all.collect { |x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

But the result set has a nil as the first value.

```
"recipes"=>["", "2", "7"]
```

How can I eliminate the empty/nil value?

Comment: `params[:recipes].reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: Does that go in the controller? And if so, which one, Meals or Recipes?

Comment: Wherever you're getting that array. Just call `.reject(&:blank?)` on it.

Comment: I added it to the controller where the error occurs and it did not work.
`def create
 meal_params[:recipes].reject(&:blank?)
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @meal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @meal, notice: 'Meal was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @meal }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @meal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: `.reject(&:blank?)` does not affect the object you called it on, it simply returns the result to you. So you either need to store the result in a variable and use that, or use the bang version of `#reject`:(`meal_params[:recipes].reject!(&:blank?)`).

Comment: I'm fairly new to ROR. I tried putting meal_params[:recipes].reject!(&:blank?) in the create method but it doesn't effect the array.

Comment: Open up console (`rails c`) and play around with `reject` and arrays. See what happens and what is returned. Once you have that knowledge, then apply it to your controller.

Comment: @XML Slayer  I've tried what you advised. In the console, what I am doing works every time. But for some reason while in the create method, the array seems immutable. Both of the following puts show the same results. 
    `
    meal_params["recipes"].each {|r| puts "RECIPE PARAM=>>#{r}<<"}
    meal_params["recipes"].shift 
    meal_params["recipes"].each {|r| puts "RECIPE PARAM=>>#{r}<<"}
    `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reject blank option by passing `:include_blank => false`

```
<%= f.select :recipes, Recipe.all.collect { |x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => false}, :multiple => true %>
```

And you can set an prompt as following

```
<%= f.select :recipes, Recipe.all.collect { |x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => "Please Select"}, :multiple => true %>
```

Comment: The problem isn't that there is a blank in the select box. The empty/blank/nil is in the result after the submit button is clicked. I want to remove or prevent the blank in the result "recipes"=>["", "2", "7"]

Comment: I've added the include_hidden and it still does not work:  <%= f.select :recipes, Recipe.all.collect { |x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, :include_hidden => false %>

Comment: It should not cause problem with saving or updating data, I found this type of empty element in my params sometimes, but no problem occur. Did you get any error? If found any error please post that, then I will try to help you to solve the error.

Comment: This is the error:

Recipe(#81240384) expected, got String(#3158916)

Rails.root: C:/Users/Michael/rails/foodian

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/meals_controller.rb:28:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"95U7L0xfW+UOXkgGFY6FPSkfJP70gV0lk2c6cnGwaxG2PALRUbZh3E4iNLf0Dn8R3tC1Z2SkcZXqdq48ltNSOw==",
 "meal"=>{"name"=>"Test meal",
 "description"=>"Try this one",
 "recipes"=>["",
 "2",
 "7"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Meal"}

Comment: Seems you have mismatch between your `model` `associations` try to fix them, this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716412/country-expected-got-string-error

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/5716412/… doesn't seem to apply since the the other values in the array are ids not strings. The hidden value is being seen as a string. I'm looking for a way to clear the empty value.I'm not sure how I can validate that  member of the collection is not empty

Answer (score 28):

For me setting `:include_hidden => false` is what worked

```
<%= f.select :recipes, Recipe.all.collect { |x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_hidden => false}, :multiple => true %>
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: There is some documentation on this [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was updating a Rails 3.2.5 app to R7 and this saved my day! To my knowledge this was not necessary under older versions of Rails, but now it is.